# Is there any method to put input box to take parameters in the lightning chart?

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I'm currently working with a LightningChart library.

The chart that I'm using is the following : https://lightningchart.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/examples/lcjs-example-0904-3dSpectrogramBox.html?theme=lightNew&page-theme=light

I've been searching for a way to put input boxes below this chart to take start and end values from a user.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find such information from either document or forum.

Does anyone know what I should try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LightningChart JS does not provide features for this kind of purposes.

I would suggest looking into HTML/CSS/JS input boxes, or to use a UI framework such as `React`, `Vue`, `Angular`, etc.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

https://reactjs.org/

In either case, the product is HTML elements that you can use for just about any UI purpose out there, not just to take start and end values from an user. These HTML elements can be aligned to the LightningChart components, for example positioning them below an Axis, etc. You can do this by "absolute positioning" the HTML elements above the chart.

Some examples can be found online on this https://lightningchart.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/search.html?t=html